# Spam backlinks on sub-domain, does it affect main domain ranking

Tags: seo, subdomain, backlinks, spam

Last year my sub-domain website (blog.domain.com) was hacked and got lots of spam articles and bad backlinks to it.

Within 1 month I deleted that sub-domain. But I had around 1500s of spam backlinks to that domain. I disvowed those also.

Even after 1 year, I have around 500 backlinks still there. How can i permanently fix this. [The sub-domain no longer exists and not even required. It was delete 1 year ago. I am concerned about the main domain]

Does it affect the ranking of my main root domain?

Comment: Same problem here. I had the subdomain "foro" on my main site, and this one was attacked by thousands of spammer backing pages. Even after a year of having deleted the subdomain, seo tools like ahrefs still show me all the backlinks spammers that redirect to that subdomain.

Answer (score 3):

Google only punishes sites or pages that are indexed. If the sub domain is no longer in it's index then there is nothing to punish, it'll only become a problem if you are redirecting the sub domain to the main domain, i.e:

- `blog.example.com` to `www.example.com/blog/`

Comment: This subdomain is no longer exists from last 1 year. But My SEO guy says that my main website is not ranking because of the bad backlinks on my subdomain. He has been working on my website SEO from last three four months.

Comment: As I said... Google can only punish sites when they exist... if you have deleted the sub domain entirely without a 301 redirect then it is impossible that a punishment can pass... ***IMPOSSIBLE***. You should  also delete the sub domain from Google Console, there is nothing to disavow and nothing to track on a site that doesn't exist.